# Suppress space before and after for /f netsh wlan show interface

Tags: variables, interface, batch-processing, netsh, wifi

OK, so the below script removes the spaces from before and after, and it works now.  I am sure there are much better ways to write this.

```
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %a in ('netsh wlan show interface^|find "Name"') do (echo %b >> c:\temp\WLANINT.txt)
    for /f "delims=" %x in (c:\temp\WLANINT.txt) do SET WLANINT=%x
    :SpaceX
    echo "%WLANINT%"
    IF "%WLANINT:~0,1%"==" " (SET WLANINT=%WLANINT:~1,-1%)
    echo "%WLANINT%"
    IF "%WLANINT:~0,1%"==" " GOTO SpaceX
    echo "%WLANINT%"
    for /l %a in (1,1,100) do if "!WLANINT:~-1!"==" " set WLANINT=!WLANINT:~0,-1!
    echo."%WLANINT%"
    netsh wlan set profileorder name="%WIFI%" interface="%WLANINT%" priority=1
    echo "%WLANINT%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next code snippet (save as `31194241.bat`; running it might require administrative privileges):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('
    netsh wlan show interface^|find "Name"
    ') do for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ("%%b") do (
  echo netsh wlan set profileorder name="%WIFI%" interface="%%x" priority=1
)
```

Changes made to your script ([read more](http://ss64.com/nt/)):

- in all `%a`, `%b`, `%c` doubled percent signs as  `%%a`, `%%b`, `%%c` for using in a `.bat` script;
- nested loops instead of creating an auxiliary file;
- `for /f "tokens=*"` will left trim blak space(s);
- productive `netsh` command is merely `echo`ed for debugging purposes only (replace `echo netsh` with `netsh` no sooner than debugged).

Instead of batch, one could use an one-liner from command line:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %a in ('netsh wlan show interface^|find "Name"') do @for /f "tokens=*" %x in ("%b") do @echo netsh wlan set profileorder name="%WIFI%" interface="%x" priority=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried them both and the command gave no error, but did not change the wireless priority.  (I know the feeling).  So I finally got my monster to work, im sure once my eyes can focus I can apply your syntax to the commands I singled out that worked to prioritize my wifi.

Comment: Sorry, I can't verify `netsh` command correctness as for `The Wireless AutoConfig Service (wlansvc) is not running.`